# Multiple caption names for listings code (lstinputlisting) based on type of code

Tags: table-of-contents, listings, environments

In my document I have used:

```
\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Algorithm}
\renewcommand\lstlistlistingname{Algorithms}
```

to rename my `lstlistings` titles.

The problem is that now I want to add a different kind of code,with `lstinputlisting` but I want it to have another caption below. Is there any way somehow to define a new `listings` environment and apply again the commands above to it?

For example ideally using two new commands `\c_lstinputlisting{testc.c}`, and `\cpp_lstinputlisting{testc.cpp}` would give two different caption names like

> C Code 1.x

and

> C++ Code 1.x

In case I am not clear, I am not talking about the caption itself, but what goes before the caption that is the general name of the caption name. Without editing it is the default

> Listing 1.x

Comment: Can you please expand a little on the way this is supposed to look like? It sounds as if you are mistaking the listing name for a caption but maybe I get you wrong.

Comment: Hi Max, yes sorry this was a mistake I meant the caption. Changed it, and also added some more stuff to make the question clearer.

Comment: @Vassilis Do you also need to produce distinct "List of C code", "List of C++ code" and so on? This would be more difficult.

Comment: @egreg I don't care much for that now, I mainly want to have two different listing environments with two different caption names. Of course it would be great if they could be two different lists in the toc but this is not my main priority.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the commands so that they change locally the meanings of the involved control sequences:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{numberbychapter}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\cinputlisting}[2][]{%
  \begingroup\let\c@lstlisting\c@clisting
  \renewcommand\lstlistingname{C file}%
  \lstinputlisting[
    language=C,
    % <other specific options>
    #1]{#2}\endgroup}

\newcommand{\cppinputlisting}[2][]{%
  \begingroup\let\c@lstlisting\c@cpplisting
  \renewcommand\lstlistingname{C++ file}%
  \lstinputlisting[
    language=C++,
    % <other specific options>
    #1]{#2}\endgroup}
\makeatother

\newcounter{clisting}[chapter]
\newcounter{cpplisting}[chapter]

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{One}
\cinputlisting[caption=something]{test.c}

\cppinputlisting[caption=whatever]{test.cpp}
\end{document}
```